# How to show kint debug info from a module on a page?

Tags: 8, debugging

In D8 I would like to display an array in the message part of a page. I did several things but could not get it work. What to do?

I installed the devel and kint modules.

I currently have changed  in services.yml the settings into:

```
debug: true   
auto_reload: true   
cache: false
```

In the twig template I added

```
{{kint("I'm working from the page.html.twig")}}
```

This is displayed in the browser, so the current theme is displaying it which proves kint is working and the correct theme is used.

So now In my module file I have

```
$data_array = json_decode($data,true);
kint($data_array);
var_dump($data_array);
return $data_array;
```

The var_dump gives a lot of data in a array. However the kint is not displayed.

How to get the kint displayed this array?

Comment: Which module file do you have this in and in which function?

Comment: In a custom module I'm building myself in a class file which is autoloaded.

Comment: 1. Where in what file and function exactly are you calling `kint()`? 2. Better use `ksm()` as it prints the variables in the messages container which by default should be placed at the top of the content area.

Answer (score 4):

Try to take a look at this site it has a lot if useful information, [print variables using kint](https://www.webwash.net/how-to-print-variables-using-kint-in-drupal-8/).

They say that if you want to output in the message area then you shall use, `ksm()`.

Comment: ksm is not displaying any info as well

Comment: Try to clear the cache.

Comment: nop, other suggestions?

Comment: Permissions error?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to run once before and to do the call different:

```
 kint_require();
```

so below code is running good

```
$data_array = json_decode($data,true);
    kint_require();
    \kint::dump($data_array);
return $data_array;
```

Comment: This doesn't explain why kint() of devel/kint doesn't run, which is probably a permissions error as @Jdrupal commented in the other answer.

Comment: That could be but I cannot confirm it as  the permission listed into drupal the king/ admin are correctly set in my configuration.

Comment: If you bypass permissions anyone can see the debug messages, don't forget to remove it then before going online ;-)